# STS on MacOS Error: Cannot find main class (I've tried every solution I can find)

Tags: java, macos, spring-tool-suite

I'm relatively new to programming.  I recently installed Spring Tool Suite (the only option I found for the Mac install was for a 64bit version) for Mac on my system, and after installing I created a test project using a java main class to sys out "hello world" to the console.  Everything was going swell until I tried to compile and run the program.  The console spat back out at me "Error: Cannot find the main class TestApp" (Test App was the name of my main class).  I checked it for errors, found none.  I thought originally that the project was bad, so I deleted it and created a new project with a similar name.  This project returned the same error.

I did some research and found that occasionally the .metadata file for a workspace can be corrupted, so I tried deleting that file, and reopening an STS workspace from the folder to regenerate it.  This didn't work, so I tried creating a new file and starting a workspace there, then importing my test project into the new workspace.  This also returned the same error.
So then I thought maybe my build path had been corrupted, so I checked and it was pointing to the correct files.  I verified that the compiler is working and compiling the run, as the generated bin folder had a binary file in the project had a file in it.  I tried   I tried deleting the run config and starting over.  Still no luck.

I tried project=> Clean, then re-running, then tried deleting the .bin file and re-running, which compiled and created a new binary file, but still returned the same error in the console.

I tried an uninstall and reinstall of STS, deleted all of the folders for my workspaces, and created new folders.
I tried fiddling around in the project libraries to see if any dependencies were missing, and found nothing.

I tried starting a SpringBoot app to see if maybe running Maven for dependencies would help somehow?

Someone suggested it may be an issue with my machine being older, and sure it's old, but it's fully updated, has an i5 processor, 16 gigs ram, and a full TB of storage.  I would be really surprised if that were the issue.
These were all of the solutions that I could find, and I may have tried a few other things that I can't remember (I've been at it for the whole day now).

Does anyone have an idea what may be going on here?  I'm at that point where punching the computer seems like a possibility.  If it is my machine, I know that using the Eclipse IDE with an STS plugin may be more lightweight, but I've heard that the plugin is also kind of a pain to work with.  Currently I've just uninstalled STS again, and may try installing again if I can find a new solution to try.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  A fundamental requirement of any question about code is that you must include the code in your question.  Please copy/paste the class into the question editor, then highlight the code and click the `{}` button in the editor toolbar to indent it and make it format as code.

Comment: Does your main class include the method declaration `public static void main(String[] args) {...`?

Comment: Post your code. We can't help you if we can't see what you're doing.

Comment: I figured it out finally.  The problem wasn't within my code, but the preferences that STS were running on were trying to pull different JRE's.  I reconfigured them and changed every instance I could find of a JDK or JRE version in the preferences to v1.8.  I'll be sure to post code with my questions in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some further research I came across a way to reconfigure JRE's.  I'm not 100% sure of what I did to fix it, but after a full reinstall and new repo folder, I went to configure JRE's when creating a project and set both options to v1.8 .  It's working now!